# How to insert dynamic values to select query (for a date range )in Cassandra using node js

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cqlsh

var result = 'select message from people.users where event_time > ? and event_time < ? allow filtering';

```
client.execute(result,[startdate,enddate], function(err,result)
```

This is not working its showing :

```
GET /favicon.ico 500 17.785 ms - 386
{ [ResponseError: Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (10)]
  name: 'ResponseError',
  message: 'Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (10)',
  info: 'Represents an error message from the server',
  code: 8704,
  query: 'select message from people.users where event_time > ? and event_time <
 ? allow filtering' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mismatch between the type expected by Cassandra (timestamp) and the value provided (it looks like it is not Ecmascript `Date`).

It should be something like:

```
var startDate = new Date('2015-01-01');
var endDate = new Date();
var query = 'select message from people.users where event_time > ?' +
            ' and event_time < ? allow filtering';
client.execute(query, [startDate, endDate], { prepare: true}, callback);
```

Also, [you should use the prepare flag for best performance and for accurate type mapping between Ecmascript and Cassandra](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/nodejs-driver/2.0/nodejs-driver/reference/nodejs2Cql3Datatypes.html?scroll=cql-to-javascript-types__encoding-data).

Comment: Thanks, actually the {prepare :true} was missing.. that was the problem.